# Make ignores the rule when run for the first time

Tags: linux, makefile

SO

I can't find out why these lines are not called for the first time I run 'make' but are called the next time:

```
sb_path = sb
sb_src := $(sb_path)/src
sb_build := $(sb_path)/build
ifndef DO_NOT_GENERATE_COMMIT_INFO
commit_sb: | $(sb_bin)
        @$(sb_build)/generate-commit-info $(sb_path)

$(sb_src)/last_git_commit_info.h: | commit_sb ;
endif
```

I'm just curious because there is no file generate-commit-info file and make crashes when I call it for the second time, but it compiles my program ok for the first try.

I use script on my local machine to copy sources over ssh to another machine and to run compile.sh script there:

```
...
scp -r $sbfolder/build $sbfolder/Makefile "$buildserver:$root/$curdate"
check_retcode
scp -r $sbfolder/sb/Makefile "$buildserver:$root/$curdate/sb/"
...
ssh $buildserver "$root/compile.sh $curdate $debug"
```

compile.sh:

```
# fix Makefile: we don't have git installed here
#DO_NOT_GENERATE_COMMIT_INFO=true

#now we can compile sb
curdir="/home/tmp/kamyshev/sb_new/$1"
cd $curdir
check_retcode
t_path=$curdir
debug=$2
config=RELEASE
if [[ debug -eq 1 ]]; then
        config=DEBUG
fi
echo "building sb... CONFIG=$config"
make -j2 CONFIG=$config
check_retcode
```

As you see `DO_NOT_GENERATE_COMMIT_INFO=true` is commented out. So I just don't see a reason why the code is not run when I call a make or the script for the first time (either from the remote script or myselft from command line).

Do you have any clues?

UPDATE on Etan Reisner comment:

commit_sb target is checked, it does not exist, so it's rule is being run and it updates `last_git_commit_info.h`. Thus it forces to update the .h file. It also gives me a .PHONY target commit_sb so I could do it directly by calling `make commit_sb`.

The `generate-commit-info` also creates a file in a `$(sb_bin)` folder.

My another guess is that you are talking about a better way to organize this code.
I can update `last_git_commit_info.h` directly with a such rule:

```
commit_sb $(sb_src)/last_git_commit_info.h: FORCE | $(sb_bin)
    @$(sb_build)/generate-commit-info $(sb_path)

FORCE:
```

Comment: Without seeing more of the makefile (and more of its output the first and second times) I can't say much for certain but the fact that your `last_git_commit_info.h` rule doesn't create that file probably isn't helping you at all, make doesn't generally like that unless the target is `.PHONY`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Can you give us a [minimal complete example](http://www.sscce.org/)? Try executing Make from the command line, without `compile.sh` or the script that calls it; the results of that experiment will narrow things down quite a lot.

Comment: @Etan Reisner, `last_git_commit_info.h` already exists, the `generate-commit-info` script updates the file with actual info and `commit_sb` is a `.PHONY` target. Anyway, I've found the reason.

Comment: Ah. I think you want a force target prereq for `last_git_commit_info.h` instead of the `.PHONY` prereq if you want that to always run. They have slightly different semantics and behaviours.

Comment: @Etan Reisner, do you mean that `@$(sb_build)/generate-commit-info $(sb_path)` rule is not remade every-time `| commit_sb` order-only prerequisite is checked? Or that I can rewrite this code in a easier to understand way?
I'll make an update to a question now, it's not possible to write much code in comments.

Comment: @Etan Reisner I want both to force `last_git_commit_info.h` update and to get a `.PHONY` target to be called directly. Also this script updates some other files in `$(sb_bin)` folder that are not used in a compilation directly.

Comment: In my experience when you have a `.PHONY` target (tgtA) as the prereq of a non-`.PHONY` target (tgtB) and that non-`.PHONY` target (tgtB) is itself the prereq of another target (tgtC). When tgtC needs to be built make will always build tgtB (because it considers the `.PHONY` tgtA as 'always new') but does *not* always build tgtA itself. So yes, that updated force version is more what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the commenters on my question I've done some additional research: I've tried to make a minimal complete example. And this led me to the answer.

My code generates dependency files (look at `-MMD` command in `SB_CXXFLAGS`):

```
# just example - in real Makefile these are calculated on the fly
sb_deps := file1.d file2.d [...]

# rules with dependances of .o files against .h files
-include $(sb_deps)

SB_CXXFLAGS = $(CXXFLAGS) [...] -MMD
# compile and generate dependency info;
$(sb_obj)/%.o:$(sb_src)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(SB_CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

And when I run make for the first time there no `*.d` files, so no `*.cpp` depends on `last_git_commit_info.h` file and the rule is not applied.
On the subsequent runs the dependency rule appears in one of `*.d` files, the rule is executed and I get the error.

UPDATE: This does not concern the question directly, but this is the better way to write these rules:

```
ifndef DO_NOT_GENERATE_COMMIT_INFO
commit_sb $(sb_src)/last_git_commit_info.h: FORCE | $(sb_bin)
    @$(sb_build)/generate-commit-info $(sb_path)

FORCE:
endif
```